# jsfiddle error {"error": "Please use POST request"} when submitting a form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input, jsfiddle

I'm new to using JSfiddle and get this error: `{"error": "Please use POST request"}` everytime I submit the form. What I have understood, you cannot submit a post request in JSfiddle, so how I can append something to a form?

```
<form>
  <label>Add</label>
  <input type="text"/>
</form>  

$('form').on("submit", function(){
  $('form').after("apple")
});
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you do not explicitly set a form method browsers will default to using GET.

```
<form method="POST">
```